# NTP local server is returning Per clock stratum: unspecified or invalid (0)

Tags: ntp

I have currently installed a ntp server on my computer and I am trying to set it up as a ntp server for some devices within my network.

I have configured the ntp.conf as fallows:

```
server  127.127.1.0
fudge   127.127.1.0 stratum 10

restrict 127.0.0.1
restrict 192.168.0.0 mask 255.255.255.0
# /etc/ntp.conf, configuration for ntpd; see ntp.conf(5) for help

driftfile /var/lib/ntp/ntp.drift

broadcastdelay  0.008
```

I have modified the ntp.conf several times. This is the last configuration I set, but with the same results.

As I restart the ntp with sudo /etc/init.d/ntp restart, I notice in Wireshark that I get a **Peer Clock Stratum: unspecified or invalid (0)**.

I pretend to set up the server for the device with the 192.168.0.2 address.

ntpq -pcrv result:

```
     remote           refid      st t when poll reach   delay   offset  jitter
==============================================================================
 LOCAL(0)        .LOCL.          10 l   34   64    7    0.000    0.000   0.000
associd=0 status=c016 leap_alarm, sync_unspec, 1 event, restart,
version="ntpd 4.2.8p10@1.3728-o Sun May  7 22:26:51 UTC 2017 (1)",
processor="x86_64", system="Linux/4.9.0-2-amd64", leap=11, stratum=16,
precision=-24, rootdelay=0.000, rootdisp=2.445, refid=INIT,
reftime=00000000.00000000  Thu, Feb  7 2036  7:28:16.000,
clock=dcce6047.fd9f268b  Tue, May 23 2017  9:16:23.990, peer=0, tc=3,
mintc=3, offset=0.000000, frequency=0.000, sys_jitter=0.000000,
clk_jitter=0.000, clk_wander=0.000
```

What am I doing wrong? Obviously, the devices don't use the date I am trying to set.

My purpose is to use this server to serve the date to my local network, so I guess that changing the server's local time should change the time of my network's devices, that is what I need.

I have done some research about this, but I haven't found anything helpful yet.

Best regards.

Iván.

Comment: what does `ntpq -pcrv` show ? I suspect nothing - I'll post my production config for you to try presuming this is a standard ntpd

Comment: I have updated the post a bit with my last ntp.conf and with the ntpq -pcrv result, but I am still getting an unspecified or invalid stratum.

Answer (score 3):

Well. My ntp.conf is correct, ntp needs several minutes to gather enough statistics in order to give a valid stratum.

I hope this was helpful for someone.

Thanks, but the person who voted me negatively ¬¬.

Comment: Ideally you want a few external low stratum servers for your server to get the time from rather than the local clock on its own.